# Why is $1 matching the whole grouping and not its token?

Tags: parsing, bison, flex-lexer, yacc

I have a Yacc grammar file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int yylex();
void yyerror (const char *s);

%}

%union {
    char* str;
}

%start line

%token <str> identifier string

%%

line: assignment    {;}
    ;

assignment: identifier '=' string   {printf("Assigning %s to val %s", $1, $3);}
          ;

%%

int main(void)
{
    return yyparse();
}

void yyerror (const char *s) {fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);}
```

and a lex file:

```
%{
    #include "y.tab.h"
    void yyerror (char *s);
    int yylex();

    int numlines = 0;
%}

%%

    /* Whitespace */
[ \t\n]            ;

    /* Comments */
\/\/.*$       ;

[a-zA-Z\_][a-zA-Z0-9\_]* {yylval.str = yytext; return identifier;}
[\'\"].*?[\'\"]          {yylval.str = yytext; return string;}

[\=\-\+\/\*\^]     return yytext[0];

.                  {fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected character `%s` \n", yytext);}

%%

int yywrap(void) {return 1;}
```

And when I run my parser with the input `var = "some string"` it outputs: `Assigning var = "some string" to val "some string"`

Why is `$1` matching the whole assignment and not just `var`?

P.S. I know many other things are wrong with this code (missing recursion, regex bugs, etc.) but this is just for reproducibility.

Comment: Because you're relying on *flex* working the way you think it does, instead of the way it actually does. You need `yylval.str = strdup(yytext)`, not just copying the pointer; and make sure you release it when you're done with it

Comment: @user207421 See, I thought this might have been the case, but I added the line `printf("%s", yylval.str);` and it gave the output `"var"` which is why I thought that was not the issue. Anyway, thanks for the help!